# Json data to label

Tags: ios, json, swift, label

I have been struggling with this for a while and just need some quick help with this basic question.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil
    {
        print ("Error!")
    }
    else
    {
        if let content = data
        {
            do
            {
                // Array
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                if let rates = myJson["bpi"] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let currency = rates["USD"] as NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let money = currency["rate"]
                        {
                            print(money)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
task.resume()

self.label.text = (self.money as String?)
```

I am trying to pass the numerical value for "money" to a label in my view controller.

Comment: Unrelated but why are you using `NSDictionary` in Swift? Use a Swift dictionary. Don't use mutable containers option in Swift. Don't use `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you are trying to update the label from outside the completion handler of your asynchronous network request. However, there are several other issues with your code. You shouldn't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use `[String:Any]` when parsing JSON dictionaries. `.mutableContainers` also doesn't have any effect in Swift. Also make sure that you dispatch any UI related updates to the main thread.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else {
        print(error!); return
    }
    do {
        if let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [String:Any],
           let rates = myJson["bpi"] as? [String:Any],
           let currency = rates["USD"] as? [String:Any],
           let money = currency["rate"] as? String {
               DispatchQueue.main.async{
                  self.label.text = money
               }
        }
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: No, the main issue is there was no attempt to update a label (on any thread).

Comment: @rmaddy actually there was an attempt: `self.label.text = (self.money as String?)`, but it was outside the completion handler as I said, the issue wasn't have to do with threads indeed

Comment: Oops. I didn't scroll down to that last line in the question, I was looking at the `print`. So the problem was trying to update the label long before the async data load was even started.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand my mistakes now and it works!

Comment: @Rob thanks for the heads up, I missed some `?` indeed, corrected it now and merged the `if` statements into one

Comment: @Rob right, I missed the else statement. The `error` and `data` parameters can only be exlusively `nil` as stated by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask), so it's enough to check one of the two: _"If the request completes successfully, the data parameter of the completion handler block contains the resource data, and the error parameter is nil. If the request fails, the data parameter is nil and the error parameter contain information about the failure."_

Comment: Quick question, if the json file is in an array, how would I cast it so I could output to the label? (in other words: what would I replace [String: Any] with)

Comment: @AleksanderFicek generally, an array of dictionaries (`[[String:Any]]`) if that's what the JSON response contains